# How to redirect using @if or @foreach

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to make the "@if and @foreach" to redirect to {{route('viewwallet',$data->address)}} page directly if wallet is available instead of showing the files between.

```
<div class="row g-gs">
@if(count($wallet) > 0)
@foreach($wallet as $data)

    <div class="col-lg-5 col-xl-4">
        <div class="card card-bordered is-dark">
            <div class="nk-wgw">
                <div class="nk-wgw-inner">
                    <a class="nk-wgw-name" href="{{route('viewwallet',$data->address)}}">
                        <div class="nk-wgw-icon is-default"><em class="icon ni ni-{{$coin->symbol}}"></em></div>
                        <h5 class="nk-wgw-title title">{{$coin->name}}</h5>
                    </a>
                    <div class="nk-wgw-balance">
                        <div class="amount">{{$data->balance}}<span class="currency currency-nio"> {{$coin->currency}}</span></div>
                        <div class="amount-sm">{{number_format($coin->price * $data->balance, $basic->decimal)}} <span class="currency currency-usd">USD</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nk-wgw-actions">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><em class="icon ni ni-scan"></em> <span>{{$data->address}}</span></a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="nk-wgw-more dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-icon btn-trigger" data-toggle="dropdown"><em class="icon ni ni-more-h"></em></a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-xs dropdown-menu-right">
                        <ul class="link-list-plain sm">
                            <li><a href="{{route('viewwallet',$data->address)}}">Details</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

And make the "else" to display if no wallet is/has been created by user

```
    @else

     <div class="nk-block">
        <div class="card card-bordered h-100">
            <div class="nk-wgw-add">
                <div class="nk-wgw-inner">
                    <a href="{{route('createwallet',$id)}}">
                        <div class="add-icon"><em class="icon ni ni-plus"></em></div>
                        <h6 class="title">Add New Wallet</h6>
                    </a>
                    <span class="sub-text">You currently have no active Bitcoin wallet yet. Click on Add New Wallet to create a wallet. </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endif

    </div>
</div>

@stop
```

i tried many ways but still not working

Comment: Your code already has anchor-link, which you for some reason call redirection; Do you really ask how to delete lines of HTML?

Comment: The looks exactly like the problem that you described, so what is not working.

Comment: i want users to be redirected to this page is wallet is already created by user or if user already have a wallet created already "{{route('viewwallet',$data->address)}}" in no wallet have been created or maybe a new user, let the @else to display for users to create a wallet